# UICollectionView Layout customization

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a lot of section and items. When I touch button in cell it create cell with 4 items in 1 cell (like expanded table) touch again cell disappear.

I found [`WaterfallCollectionView`](https://github.com/frogermcs/WaterfallCollectionView) and there I can change height of items.

What is the best way to achieve this???

Structure like:

```
 -----      -----
|    +|    |    +|   and other rows
|     |    |     |
 -----      -----
```

When I touch my button (+) it should be like:

```
 -----      -----     -----
|    -|    |__|__|   |    +|
|     |    |  |  |   |     |
 -----      -----     -----
```

A new cell create with 4 UIImageView's inside 1 cell ( if 4 elements in 1 cell, if more create more cell). If 1 element create this cell but image will be in the top left corner.
Where in cells should be my info (like expanded table)

Is it better to create different type of cells?

Comment: if cell is as simple as you have shown and no need different cells then you can go ahead with [expand table](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview)

Comment: @cjd I need different cells.

Comment: I hope [collapseclick](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/collapseclick) will help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried something out where a `UICollectionViewCell` is made to expand by changing its own size. The new 'cells' that pop out when you tap on a cell are not really new cells, but subviews of the original cell. Essentially it works something like this:

1. Use `UICollectionView` with a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
2. The `UICollectionView`'s delegate conforms to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implements `-collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` to recognize unique cell sizes.
3. The `UICollectionView`'s delegate implements `-collectionView:didSelectCellAtIndexPath:` where it adjusts the cell's size to reveal or hide the subviews that look like new cells.
4. A custom object representing the cell's contents and a custom `UICollectionViewCell` subclass are used to make it easier to perform and keep track of expansion.

I created an [example project here](https://github.com/ykjchen/ExpandableCollectionView) which has a cells that expand to show a number's divisors. It looks something like this:

[image]

The project is pretty rough and uncommented, and the transition happens without animation, but if you find this approach interesting and cannot follow the code I can clean it up a bit.

And here's the code dump...

`CollectionViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

`CollectionViewController.m`

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CellDataItem.h"
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewController () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *cellData;

@end

NSString *const kCollectionViewCellIdentifier = @"Cell";

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (NSMutableArray *)cellData
{
    if (!_cellData) {
        NSInteger countValues = 20;
        _cellData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:countValues];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < countValues; i++) {
            CellDataItem *item = [[CellDataItem alloc] init];
            item.number = @(arc4random() % 100);
            [_cellData addObject:item];
        }
    }
    return _cellData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = [CollectionViewCell sizeWithDataItem:nil];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = [CollectionViewCell margin];
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = layout.minimumInteritemSpacing;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    _collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
                                         collectionViewLayout:layout];
    _collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    _collectionView.dataSource = self;
    _collectionView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[CollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionViewCellIdentifier];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.bounds.size.width, layout.itemSize.height);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.cellData.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kCollectionViewCellIdentifier
                                                         forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.dataItem = [self.cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [CollectionViewCell sizeWithDataItem:[self.cellData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell toggleExpansion];
    [collectionView reloadData];
}

@end

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CellDataItem : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *number;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *divisors;
@property (nonatomic, getter = isExpanded) BOOL expanded;

@end
```

`CellDataItem.m`

```
#import "CellDataItem.h"

@interface CellDataItem ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *divisors;

@end

@implementation CellDataItem

+ (NSArray *)divisorsForNumber:(NSNumber *)number
{
    NSMutableArray *divisors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@(1), number, nil];
    float root = pow(number.doubleValue, 0.5);
    if (root == roundf(root)) {
        [divisors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)root]];
    }

    NSInteger maxDivisor = (NSInteger)root;
    for (NSInteger divisor = 2; divisor < maxDivisor; divisor++) {
        float quotient = number.floatValue / (float)divisor;
        if (quotient == roundf(quotient)) {
            [divisors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:divisor]];
            [divisors addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)quotient]];
        }
    }
    return [divisors sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
}

- (void)setNumber:(NSNumber *)number
{
    if (_number == number) {
        return;
    }
    _number = number;
    self.divisors = [self.class divisorsForNumber:_number];
}

@end
```

`CollectionViewCell.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CellDataItem;
@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

+ (CGFloat)margin;
+ (CGSize)sizeWithDataItem:(CellDataItem *)dataItem;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CellDataItem *dataItem;

- (void)toggleExpansion;

@end

@interface ChildView : UIView

- (UILabel *)labelAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;
- (void)clearLabels;

@end
```

`CollectionViewCell.m`

```
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "CellDataItem.h"

@interface CollectionViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *childViews;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UILabel *numberLabel;

@end

NSInteger const kCollectionViewCellSplitCount = 4;
CGFloat const kCollectionViewCellMargin = 20.0f;
CGSize const kCollectionViewCellDefaultSize = {200.0f, 200.0f};

@implementation CollectionViewCell

+ (CGFloat)margin
{
    return kCollectionViewCellMargin;
}

+ (CGSize)sizeWithDataItem:(CellDataItem *)dataItem
{
    if (dataItem && dataItem.isExpanded) {
        CGSize size = kCollectionViewCellDefaultSize;
        NSInteger childViewsRequired = [self childViewsRequiredForDataItem:dataItem];
        size.width += childViewsRequired * ([self margin] + size.width);
        return size;
    } else {
        return kCollectionViewCellDefaultSize;
    }
}

+ (NSInteger)childViewsRequiredForDataItem:(CellDataItem *)dataItem
{
    return (NSInteger)ceilf((float)dataItem.divisors.count / (float)kCollectionViewCellSplitCount);
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        _numberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _numberLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        _numberLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        _numberLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        _numberLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_numberLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setDataItem:(CellDataItem *)dataItem
{
    if (_dataItem == dataItem) {
        return;
    }

    _dataItem = dataItem;
    self.numberLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", dataItem.number.integerValue];

    if (!dataItem.expanded) {
        [self collapse];
    } else if (dataItem.expanded) {
        [self expand];
    }
}

- (void)collapse
{
    for (ChildView *view in self.childViews) {
        view.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)expand
{
    NSInteger childViewsRequired = [self.class childViewsRequiredForDataItem:self.dataItem];
    while (self.childViews.count < childViewsRequired) {
        ChildView *childView = [[ChildView alloc] init];
        [self.childViews addObject:childView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:childView];
    }

    NSInteger index = 0;
    for (ChildView *view in self.childViews) {
        view.hidden = !(index < childViewsRequired);
        if (!view.hidden) {
            [view clearLabels];
        }
        index++;
    }

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.dataItem.divisors.count; i++) {
        NSInteger labelsPerChild = 4;
        NSInteger childIndex = i / labelsPerChild;
        NSInteger labelIndex = i % labelsPerChild;
        [[[self.childViews objectAtIndex:childIndex] labelAtIndex:labelIndex] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [[self.dataItem.divisors objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]]];
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat const unitWidth = kCollectionViewCellDefaultSize.width;
    CGFloat const unitHeight = kCollectionViewCellDefaultSize.height;
    CGFloat const margin = [self.class margin];
    self.numberLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, unitWidth, unitHeight);

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.childViews.count; i++) {
        ChildView *view = [self.childViews objectAtIndex:i];
        view.frame = CGRectMake((i + 1) * (margin + unitWidth), 0.0f, unitWidth, unitHeight);
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray *)childViews
{
    if (!_childViews) {
        _childViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _childViews;
}

- (void)toggleExpansion
{
    self.dataItem.expanded = !self.dataItem.isExpanded;
    if (self.dataItem.isExpanded) {
        [self expand];
    } else {
        [self collapse];
    }
}

@end

@interface ChildView ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *labels;

@end

@implementation ChildView

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (UILabel *)labelAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    if (!self.labels) {
        self.labels = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    while (self.labels.count <= index) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
        label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        [self.labels addObject:label];
        [self addSubview:label];
    }

    return [self.labels objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (void)clearLabels
{
    for (UILabel *label in self.labels) {
        label.text = nil;
    }
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat labelWidth = self.bounds.size.width * 0.5f;
    CGFloat labelHeight = self.bounds.size.height * 0.5f;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.labels.count; i++) {
        UILabel *label = [self.labels objectAtIndex:i];
        NSInteger x = i % 2;
        NSInteger y = i / 2;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(x * labelWidth, y * labelHeight, labelWidth, labelHeight);
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want expandable cells you have to insert the new cells inside the collection view by calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` on your collection view.

It is not trivial as you have to shift all your index paths, update the number of items in the section to reflect the newly added cells, etc. If you are looking for something simple then the Waterfall example is good. If you want a more complex / configurable solution then you have to rock your own custom layout. That's what I did.