# which approch to follow for implementing UICollectionView?ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uilabel, uicollectionview

In my requirement I am using `UICollectionView` in which I am showing `UIImageView`,`UILabel`,`UITextView`.
What I have to do when there is no image in my cell I have to shift the `label` & `text` sightly upwards.

I am passing `nil` in `imageArray` and applying condition `if(imageView.image==nil){ //  shift label upward  }`
but this is shifting all label to upward .
What to do?
Which approach should I follow?

Comment: I suggest you to follow some good tutorials here are the links of some below: **1)** http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial **2)** http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html **3)** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947371/uicollectionview-layout-customization Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Shift labels back down when image is not nil.

Use harcoded frames for both cases.

```
if (imageView.image == nil) label.frame = frameOne;
else label.frame = frameTwo;
```